# table of content problem in tex4ht. missing numbering at level subsubsection and alignment is not correct

Tags: table-of-contents, tex4ht, make4ht

I am not sure what I am doing wrong here. I need to produce this toc in book class

[image]

But in html it looks like this

[image]

The following is the MWE and the commands used to compile it. I think I added all the needed code for tex4ht, but it is not working. I must be missing some additional option?

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}   
\else 
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\fi 

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{book name}
my book
\section{section name}
section data
\subsection{subsection name}
subsection data
\subsubsection{subsubsection name}
subsubsection data
\paragraph{paragraph name}
paragraph data

\end{document}
```

The command to compile it to html is

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "mathjax,htm"
```

I tried also

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  foo.tex "mathjax,htm,fn-in,notoc*"
```

No difference. I always tried without `\frontmatter` and it made no difference.

How to add numbering to `subsubsection` and to `paragraph` and why is `paragraph` entry is not aligned as the PDF toc shows?

TL 2022.

```
>which latex
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/latex
>which make4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/make4ht
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this configuration file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph}   
\catcode`\:=11
\makeatletter
\ConfigureMark{paragraph}{\ifnum \c:secnumdepth>\c@secnumdepth\expandafter\:gobble
    \else
       \HCode{<span class="titlemark">}\@seccntformat{paragraph}%
       \HCode{</span>}\fi}
\Configure{paragraph}{}{}
  {\par\ShowPar\IgnoreIndent\HCode{<span
      class="paragraphHead"\a:LRdir>}\begingroup\bf\TitleMark}
  {\endgroup\HCode{</span>}\IgnorePar}
\Css{.paragraphToc{margin-left:8em;}}

\NewConfigure{tableofcontents*}[1]{%
   \def\:tempa{#1}\ifx\empty\:tempa
      \ifx \au:StartSec\:UnDef \else \gdef\:StartSec{\au:StartSec}\fi
   \else
      \edef\auto:toc{#1}%
         \ifx \au:StartSec\:UnDef
            \let\au:StartSec\:StartSec
            \def\:StartSec{\:tableofcontents
               \global\let\auto:toc\:UnDef \let\:StartSec\au:StartSec \:StartSec}%
            \pend:def\tableofcontents{\gdef\:StartSec{\au:StartSec}}%
   \fi  \fi
}
\makeatother
\catcode`\:=12
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

It declares the sectioning levels to be printed in TOC using `\Configure{tableofcontents*}`, and then fixes handling of `paragraph` numbering in the text with `\Configure{paragraph}`, where I've added the `\TitleMark` command to print the number, and `\ConfigureMark{paragraph}`, which configures the number itself. I also had to fix `\NewConfigure{tableofcontetns*}`, because it would print the TOC twice otherwise.

You can then simplify your document:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{my book}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}


\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{book name}
my book
\section{section name}
section data
\subsection{subsection name}
subsection data
\subsubsection{subsubsection name}
subsubsection data
\paragraph{paragraph name}
paragraph data

\end{document}
```

And this is the result:

[image]