# tex4ht no longer shows table of content when using split level after updating to latest TL 2022

Tags: tex4ht, make4ht

I found two big problems so far after I just updated to latest TL 2022 2 hrs ago.

So I will post two separate questions on these. If I find more, will add separate questions.

I found that table of content no longer shows up on the webpage when using split level. The index.htm has basically an empty body.

If I do not use split level, then it does show. But this is not how it is supposed to be.

Here is a MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}%
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter
\title{my book title}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle

\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter}   
\TocAt{chapter,section}
\TocAt{section,subsection}
\TocAt{subsection,subsubsection}
\TocAt{subsubsection,paragraph}
\fi 

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{First order ode $F\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)  =0$}%
data
\section{First order linear in derivative $F\left(  x,y,y^{\prime}\right)=0$}%
These are first order ode's which are linear in $y^{\prime}$.
\subsection{Quadrature ode $y^{\prime}=f\left(  x\right)  $}
data
\subsubsection{Introduction}
data
\end{document}
```

Compiled using

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  index.tex 'mathjax,htm,4'
```

This is the HTML generated

[image]

This is the raw html

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html lang='en-US' xml:lang='en-US'> 
<head><title>my book title</title> 
<meta charset='utf-8' /> 
<meta content='TeX4ht (https://tug.org/tex4ht/)' name='generator' /> 
<meta content='width=device-width,initial-scale=1' name='viewport' /> 
<link href='index.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' /> 
<meta content='index.tex' name='src' /> 
<script>window.MathJax = { tex: { tags: "ams", }, }; </script> 
 <script async='async' id='MathJax-script' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/mathjax@3/es5/tex-chtml-full.js' type='text/javascript'></script>  
</head><body>
<!-- l. 10 --><p class='indent'>
</p>   
<div class='maketitle'>
<h2 class='titleHead'>my book title</h2>
<div class='author'><span class='ec-lmr-12x-x-120'>me</span></div><br />
<div class='date'><span class='ec-lmr-12x-x-120'>December 26, 2022</span></div>
                                                                          
</div>
</body> 
</html>
```

You can see, empty body.   This happens when asking for a split level. changing `4` to `3` or `2` in the command

```
 make4ht -ulm default -a debug  index.tex 'mathjax,htm,4'
```

makes no difference. Main page is empty. So something went badly wrong somewhere.

```
>which tex4ht
/usr/local/texlive/2022/bin/x86_64-linux/tex4ht
>make4ht --version
make4ht version v0.3l
```

Ticket https://puszcza.gnu.org.ua/bugs/?588

### Update

Found the problem!!

Changed

```
\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter}   
\TocAt{chapter,section}
\TocAt{section,subsection}
\TocAt{subsection,subsubsection}
\TocAt{subsubsection,paragraph}
\fi

\tableofcontents
```

TO

```
\ifdefined\HCode 
\Configure{tableofcontents*}{chapter}   
\TocAt{chapter,section}
\TocAt{section,subsection}
\TocAt{subsection,subsubsection}
\TocAt{subsubsection,paragraph}
\else 
\tableofcontents
\fi
```

Basically, one should not issue `\tableofcontents` in tex4ht mode.

Now the table of content shows up using the command

```
make4ht -ulm default -a debug foo.tex 'mathjax,htm,4'
```

Raw HTML now shows toc

```
</p>   
<div class='tableofcontents'>
<span class='chapterToc'>1 <a href='foch1.htm#first-order-ode-fleft-xyy-right-' id='QQ2-2-1'>First order ode \(F\o:left: ( x,y,y^{\prime }\o:right: ) =0\)</a></span>
</div> 
</body> 
</html>
```

It was the issuing of `\tableofcontents` in tex4ht which made it not show toc!

Btw, this could be related to this change?  [table of content problem in tex4ht. missing numbering at level subsubsection and alignment is not correct](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/668713/table-of-content-problem-in-tex4ht-missing-numbering-at-level-subsubsection-and)

> I also had to fix \NewConfigure{tableofcontetns*}, because it would
> print the TOC twice otherwise.

I do not know. But for now, I am OK and will just make sure not to use `\tableofcontents` in tex4ht mode.

Comment: I suspect that this will be related to the recent change to `\Configure{tableofcontents*}`, but I will take a look at this issue later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that when you use `\tableofcontents` in document broken into several files, the TOC itself will be saved to a separate file, because it the TOC title is printed as a section. This can be fixed when you remove the TOC title, for example using this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\begin{document}
\let\contentsname\empty
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Ok, thanks. Do you see an issue of using my workaround instead? i.e. just avoid using `\tableofcontents` in tex4ht mode and use `\Configure{tableofcontents*}` instead as I showed? This way I do not have to make changes, or do you think your solution will be better for some other reasons?

Comment: @Nasser your workaround is fine too